# Windows 7 freezes at Windows Logo on Startup and then boots up completely after roughly 20 seconds

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, drivers, freeze

I have recently noticed that Windows 7 will freeze during startup, specifically while the Windows Logo is midway from forming. After this occurs, I will usually just have to turn my computer off and then on again. When I do this, Windows will boot up normally with no errors. If I wait, the computer will automatically continue booting up after roughly 20 seconds have passed.

Originally, I suspected this may have been a driver issue with Wacom as I received an error from one of the drivers however after removing them completely the problem persisted. I also attempted to restore Windows to a time when it was function properly using Restore Points with no effect.

I have recently flashed (updated) my BIOS and installed a 2nd Nvidia GTX 680 in SLI mode. I have also recently updated my Nvidia Drivers.

**What could be causing this problem?**

Edit: here is where it freezes. Sorry about the quality!

[image: where it freezes]

Comment: If you boot to Safe mode, does the same thing happen?  Have you tested your disk/file system for corruption yet (`chkdsk`)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I have done both. Safe mode is fine and, like I said, after waiting I am able to boot into the computer normally. I checked all of my discs and they are also good.

Comment: "Safe mode is fine" So if you boot in Safe Mode, it doesn't do the 20 hang at the logo?  Was this hang happening before you flashed your BIOS and install the 2nd video adapter?  do oyu have any other peripherals connected to the PC (printers, scanners, joysticks, etc.)?

Comment: Its tough to say definitively as I don't believe I saw a Windows Logo Splash screen when you go into Safe Mode. This all happened after I flashed the BIOS and installed the 2nd GPU. However, when I disconnect all peripherals, the freeze does not occur.

Comment: My PSU is a Corsair 860w so it should be able to handle the power draw.

Comment: "However, when I disconnect all peripherals, the freeze does not occur." then try disconnecting one peripheral at a time, until you find the culprit. once you've narrowed down the culprit, then you should be able to start troubleshooting it.

Comment: So it appears that whenever I have more than one peripheral device connected, this problem occurs (i.e. freezes when both mouse and keyboard are connected but not when only the mouse is connected). This has never happened before and it does not appear to be due to any one specific product

Comment: product as in- same result regardless of brand (i.e. razor, corsair, wacom etc)

Comment: I tried disabling the Legacy USB Support and that seemed to solve the Windows Logo Freeze problem but now when I boot up I have to wait for a white cursor and black screen for several minutes

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007Any ideas? The problem does not appear to be specific to any one peripheral device. It impacts them all equally. Further, this has never been an issue prior to this.

Comment: Install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx also works for win7), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** & under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file (to reduce its size), upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aprz2hNFnku0pny4R0T29QXXaVHC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the ETL in WPA, click on `Profiles`->`Apply`->`Browse Catalog` and select the file `FullBoot.Boot.wpaprofile` you see this overview:

[image]

and see a 58s delay in `PreSessionInit/PreSMSS-Phase`

> **What Happens in This Subphase** The PreSMSS subphase begins when the kernel is invoked. During this subphase, the kernel initializes data
>   structures and components. It also starts the PnP manager, which
>   initializes the BOOT_START drivers that were loaded during the
>   OSLoader phase. When the PnP manager detects a device, it loads and
>   initializes the device’s drivers
>
> **Visual Cues** PreSMSS begins approximately when the “Loading Windows” splash screen appears. There are no explicit visual cues for
>   the end of PreSMSS.

I can see that the hang happens during ACPI operations and starting

```
<phase name="bootStart" startTime="45" endTime="58165" duration="58119">
  <pnpObject name="ACPI_HAL\PNP0C08\0" type="Device" activity="Start" startTime="50" endTime="56332" duration="56282" prePendTime="56282" description="Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System" friendlyName="" />
```

Here the `prePendTime` is 56s:

> The prePendTime indicates how long the driver processed the IRP in its
>   start or enumeration dispatch routine before it returned
>   STATUS_PENDING. This value should be as close to 0 as possible. If it
>   equals the duration, the driver did not pend the IRP.

So this is your issue. [Analyzing the ETL for hangs](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis) I can see a call of the Intel Storage driver (`iaStorA.sys`) while init all required drivers (`ntoskrnl.exe!IopInitializeBootDrivers`):

[image]

Here you see the 56s delay. Your driver version is 13.0.3.1001, which is a bit older. Try the latest version [14.8.0.1042](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/55005/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-) .

Comment: Hmm. So I updated to the latest driver in Win7 but it still seems to be hanging at the splash screen. Do I need to configure something in the BIOS as well? What else could it be aside from the driver? As a note: It has booted up successfully without delay several times since the update (maybe 2 out of the 6 attempts have been normal).

Comment: you said you updated the BIOS. Why? Do you had an issue? Can you try to flash the older version and look what happens? Also, are your disks in- or external drives? Which devices have you disconnected when the issue no longer occurs?

Comment: I updated the BIOS after my computer stopped keeping track of time (I had replaced the CMOS battery only a month prior to this) and now the time function works correctly. I have one Samsung SSD from which I boot off of and three 2tb SSHDs for storage. These are all internal drives. As I mentioned, the problem does not seem to be related to one specific brand or device. If I boot up with only my Intous tablet, the computer will be fine. If I boot up with my Corsair mouse, the computer will be fine. If I boot up with both, the computer will hang at the splash screen.

Comment: The same goes for my Razor game pad and so on. For what its worth, while I was setting up SLI (the night that this problem began), I did attempt to reinstall my PCIE drivers from the Asus disk that came with my motherboard. Maybe these are somehow outdated?

Comment: try to update all other drivers and see what happens

Comment: Alright, so thanks to your answer I did some research into the Intel Drivers I had installed (Intel Rapid Storage and USB Extensible Host). I found that they were not necessary and that, in some cases, they could be problematic when connecting USB 2.0 connectors to 3.0 ports, something I had done. I have uninstalled both and so far everything seems ok. I was able to boot up normally maybe 5 or 6 times in a row now without fail. I will keep an eye on it over the next 24-48 hours and let you know how it goes. I'll also accept the answer if everything looks good.

Comment: ok, hopefully removing the Intel driver and using the standard Microsoft drivers fixes it :)

Comment: Yes! After roughly 24 hours and probably 20 boot-ups I can confirm this was the solution. Thanks so much for the help! Your in-depth analysis led me to the solution.

Comment: WPR/WPA is a powerful tool to debug perf issues but require a giant learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

R&R video driver still froze. I disconnected all USB devices including mouse, no freeze.  Just plugged in mouse...still froze.  Tried a different mouse...froze. After testing RAM and HDD for errors and scanning for malware, no errors showed up and no malware was found.  Tried different USB port for mouse still...froze.  After plugging mouse into a 3.0 USB port it has not froze for 5 days. I have a Asus GL771JM 2014 vintage laptop.